# Getting "ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSConnection" error in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy django in AWS ElasticBeanstalk.
While I was following the steps as shown [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html), I'm stuck with the command, "eb init".
I'm using Python 2.7 in Ubuntu 12.10 (vmware)
I'm getting the error as below:

```
eb init 
.....

from lib.aws.http_client import HTTP_GET, HTTP_POST

File "/home/g/Documents/Files/AWS/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.4.0/eb/linux/python2.7/lib/aws/http_client.py", line 17, in <module>
from httplib import HTTPSConnection
ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSConnection
```

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities spring to mind...

1. The Python installation on AWS doesn't include SSL support.
2. You've created a file called `httplib.py` which is shadowing the one in the standard Python library.

Try doing `import ssl`, and if you get `ImportError: No module named _ssl`, then it's #1, otherwise it's #2.

Answer (score 1):

I had installed python via homebrew and was getting this error. For some reason the solution was to uninstall and reinstall it:

```
brew uninstall python
brew install python
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a virtual environment. I deleted the virtual environment and recreated it and the problem disappeared.