# Python 3.4 in Raspberry Pi, cannot import name httpsconnection

Tags: python, ssl, debian, python-3.4, raspbian

I was trying out python3.4 in Raspbian Wheezy, but the below given code fails

```
from http.client import HTTPSConnection
```

the error message is:

```
cannot import name httpsconnection
```

On further googling, I doubt if this has any relation with enabling SSL in python3.4 which I couldn't figure out how to..  Could someone help me out? Thanks..

Comment: *"I doubt if this has any relation with enabling SSL ... which I couldn't figure out how to do ..."* - well, that's not very reassuring. That's like asking the drunk if he's drunk and getting the answer NO... Possibly related: [Getting “ImportError: cannot import name HTTPSConnection” error in Python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16624565/608639).

Comment: Are you sure you capitalized it correctly? `HTTPSConnection` (top code) is not the same as `httpsconnection` (error message).

Comment: @MattDMo : sorry that's a mistake, yes it should be HTTPSConnection in the error code

Comment: @jww thanks for the link, but I had come across that one. If I'm referring to Aya 's answer there, it's case #1,